# Performance difference between adjacency lists vs single array for Graph

Tags: java, performance, memory, graph, cpu-cache

I tried speeding up my Graph class. My 2 implementations seem very similar, but for some reason have a 10x speed difference that I cannot figure out.

Some explanation for both of these:
I am essentially storing the adjacency list in different ways. If the edges are 0-1, 0-2, 1-3, 1-4, then the second implementation would simply store `[[1, 2], [0, 3, 4], [0], [1], [1]]` (for example, node 1 is connected with `[0, 3, 4]`).
However, the first implementation would store this as `[1,2,0,3,4,0,1,1]` (everything together in 1 array), and then track, for each node, the interval of its edges. So `l[1] = 2`, `r[1] = 4`, because node 1 has edges [0,3,4], which is at index 2-3. This only works when you have all the edges up front though, because adding/deleting would be impossible.

Fast implementation:

```
class Graph1 {
    int[] edgeEndpoints;
    int[] l, r;
    
    public Graph1(int N, int M, int[] edgeArr1, int[] edgeArr2) {
        edgeEndpoints = new int[2*M];
        l = new int[N];
        r = new int[N];
        
        //calculate degrees
        int[] nodeDegrees = new int[N];
        for(int ele : edgeArr1)
        {
            nodeDegrees[ele]++;
        }
        for(int ele : edgeArr2)
        {
            nodeDegrees[ele]++;
        }
        
        //similar to N array lists. have a pointer cnt for each node. The interval of each node is already calculated
        int[] cnt = new int[N];
        l[0] = 0;
        r[0] = nodeDegrees[0]-1;
        for(int i=1; i<N; i++) {
            l[i] = r[i-1] + 1;
            r[i] = l[i] + nodeDegrees[i] - 1;
            cnt[i] = l[i];
        }
        
        for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            int a = edgeArr1[i];
            int b = edgeArr2[i];

            edgeEndpoints[cnt[a]] = b;
            edgeEndpoints[cnt[b]] = a;
            cnt[a]++;
            cnt[b]++;
        }
    }
}
```

Regular adjacency list implementation:

```
class Graph2 {
    ArrayList<Integer>[] edgeEndpoints; 
    
    public Graph2(int N, int M, int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
        edgeEndpoints = new ArrayList[N];
        
        for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            edgeEndpoints[i] = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        
        for(int i=0; i<M; i++) {
            int a = arr1[i];
            int b = arr2[i];
            edgeEndpoints[a].add(b);
            edgeEndpoints[b].add(a);
        }
    }
}
```

I then tested both of these with a randomly generated list of edges, with 1 million nodes and 4 million edges. The first version ran in ~100ms, while the second one ran in ~1500ms. What is causing this huge difference? I suspect it is due to memory access patterns, but even in the first example, some of it is still random.

Comment: How are you measuring?  Accurately measuring performance of anything in Java is very hard.

Comment: so maybe my benchmark is causing a 10x speed difference? how is that possible

Comment: It's certainly possible. E.g. because your benchmark [unintentionally] measures GC overhead with a small initial heap. Post the entire benchmark along with the exact command how you run it.

Comment: That's quite possible because of how Java's JIT compilation works.

Comment: It could be due to resizing the array list. Try pre-sizing the list and see if that helps the second version.